# Angular highchart with dynamic data from API

Tags: angular, api, highcharts

This Angular code gets data from API and creates a Spline chart with that API data in angular highcharts.

**This is the app.component.ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
import { DashService } from './shared/dash.service';
import { Chart } from './shared/chart.model';


@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
    ChartModel: Chart[];
    url: string = 'https://localhost:44311/api/charts/';
    data: any;

   constructor(public service: DashService) { }

   Highcharts = Highcharts;

    spline = {
    chart: {
   type: 'spline',
    },
    title: {
    text: 'Active Users'
    },
    credits: {
    enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: {
      title: {
         text: 'Users'
         }
    },
    series: []
    }
    ngOnInit() {

    this.getApiResponse(this.url).then(
    data => {
    const values = [];
    data.forEach(row => {
    const temp_row = [row.data,];    
    values.push(temp_row);
    });
    var dataSeries = [];

    dataSeries.push({
    name:'Users Present',
    data: values,
    });

    this.spline.series = dataSeries;
    },
    error => {
    console.log('Something went wrong.');
    })
    }
    getApiResponse(url) {
    return this.service.Get(this.url)
    .toPromise().then(res => {
    return res;
    });
    }
    }
```

**This is dash.service.ts file**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Chart } from './chart.model';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DashService {

  readonly chartURL = "https://localhost:44311/api/charts/"
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  Get(chartURL):Observable<Chart[]>{
  return this.http.get<Chart[]>(chartURL);
 }
}
```

**This is chart.model.ts file**

```
export class Chart {
    data:number;
}
```

**And This is app.component.html**

```
<div class="chart-box" class="col-lg-5 md-5 ml-5" > 
        <highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [options]="spline"></highcharts-chart>
</div>
```

I updated my app.component.ts file and also added dash.service.ts, and model.ts file.
Now I am able to get the data for my chart from an API, the only thing I want to do is update the chart after every 5 seconds and keep adding points to it from API.

This [website](https://nicmh.attendance.gov.in/#) shows the highcharts, with dynamic data. The line chart on the right side updates in every 5 seconds,by adding points to it,and I want this too to be done in my chart.The mentioned website is not mine, it's just for the reference. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/dynamic-update/) is another reference which adds point every second, I want the same too with my chart
Please help me to make my chart dynamic like this

Below is the image of my chart
[image: This is how my chart looks like]

Comment: It is a really common question, please get familiar with: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41514

Comment: Ok I will check it and let you know, Thanks for the resource

Comment: Hey @Sebastian Wędzel , I still cannot figure out how observables are used with Highcharts, Can you please send me a clear explanation with code that can help or you may mention the changes in above code

Comment: This demo is a simulation of fetching the data from the server: https://codesandbox.io/s/l9v3vk58o7?file=/src/app/chart.component.ts have you tried to reproduce it for your requirements? May I see your attempt?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help @SebastianWędzel . I created my chart and now the data is coming from an API too, as per my requirements,Now I just want to update my chart periodically, say in a time interval of 5 seconds

Comment: I updated my code and question @SebastianWędzel please help me out with it

Comment: Here is a demo with using the `setInvertal` to fetch new data each 5 seconds: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-888c2 remember to change the updateFlag to trigger an update, more: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular

Comment: Thanks a lot @SebastianWędzel, but I am still not able to get it. Can you please explain me, how to use series.addPoint() method for dynamically adding points to chart

Comment: As you can find in the general documentation - it is advised to update the whole `chartOptions` with the new data with using the `updateFlag`, otherwise Angular could not track some changes, because using the `addPoint` change the chart data/options, not the options set in the Angular wrapper. However, it is possible to use it: https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-1v5q2 but in more complicate application some errors could appear.

Comment: Thank you @SebastianWędzel, I will try it out and let you know

Comment: Hey @SebastianWędzel please help me out with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61818622/angular-highcharts-series-name-in-piechart-with-api-data) . I have an issue with my pie chart data